# Removing duplicate records of fileA using records in fileA

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two files File A and File B,
File A contains tab separated columns and rows associated with it:

```
person Id    person Name
56783    ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent
78954    rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur
56783    rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure
78967    rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know
```

File B contains tab separated columns and rows associated with it:

```
person Id    person Name    city Name    country Name    salary
34526    paul 56 >> 78 has no idea    Tel Aviv    Isreal    60
56783    ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent    Seattle    USA    70
58783    ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent    Seattle    USA    90
39526    saul 96 >> 78 has no idea    Delhi    India    60
78954    rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur    Mumbai    India    90
98789    rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur    Mumbai    India    80
67526    delta 89 >> 78 has no idea    Tel Aviv    Isreal    50
56783    rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure    Boston    USA    79
78783    rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure    Boston    USA    79
39526    pallavi 56 >> 78 has no idea    Hyderabad    India    60
78967    rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know    Hyderabad    India    78
08960    rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know    Hyderabad    India    87
```

I want to only the records in file A to be in File B and remove other duplicate records.

For example If you notice:

```
56783    ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent    Seattle    USA    70
58783    ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent    Seattle    USA    90
```

ram is appearing twice with different id, I just want to have the same id of File A in File B and remove anything duplicate:

For example I only want to have:

```
56783    ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent    Seattle    USA    70
```

In the same way I want to have only rahim person Id in file B and remove or delete other rahim id which is not matching in two files.

Another example:

```
78954    rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur    Mumbai    India    90
98789    rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur    Mumbai    India    80
```

I only want the same person Id of file A in file B, so the only record which should in fileB os rahim is this and delete the other record:

```
78954    rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur    Mumbai    India    90
```

I am ok with any programming language, Java and Scala I prefer more. Finally, I don't want to have duplicate person names, id's are different, so I want to have the id's of file A in my file B and delete the rest in file B and then save it.

I think this can be easy on Spark, trying but no luck!!

**The final output should be this:**

```
person Id    person Name    city Name    country Name    salary
    34526    paul 56 >> 78 has no idea    Tel Aviv    Isreal    60
    56783    ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent    Seattle    USA    70
    39526    saul 96 >> 78 has no idea    Delhi    India    60
    78954    rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur    Mumbai    India    90
    67526    delta 89 >> 78 has no idea    Tel Aviv    Isreal    50
    56783    rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure    Boston    USA    79
    39526    pallavi 56 >> 78 has no idea    Hyderabad    India    60
    78967    rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know    Hyderabad    India    78
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `dataFrame` `API`s which should make your task very easy.
Read the files using `sqlContext` into `dataframe` using appropriate `delimiter` i.e `\t`
*But unfortunately* `\t` `delimiter` didn't work. So I changed the `delimiter` to `|` in the files and used following code to read into `dataFrames`

**You must find a way to read the tab delimited files A and B into dataFrame or change the delimiter as I did**

```
var df1 = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("location of file A")
```

Output would be

```
+---------+--------------------------------+
|person Id|person Name                     |
+---------+--------------------------------+
|56783    |ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent  |
|78954    |rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur     |
|56783    |rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure|
|78967    |rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know      |
+---------+--------------------------------+
```

Apply similar process for `file B` into `dataframe` `df2` would give

```
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
|person Id|person Name                     |city Name|country Name|salary|
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
|34526    |paul 56 >> 78 has no idea       |Tel Aviv |Isreal      |60    |
|56783    |ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent  |Seattle  |USA         |70    |
|58783    |ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent  |Seattle  |USA         |90    |
|39526    |saul 96 >> 78 has no idea       |Delhi    |India       |60    |
|78954    |rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur     |Mumbai   |India       |90    |
|98789    |rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur     |Mumbai   |India       |80    |
|67526    |delta 89 >> 78 has no idea      |Tel Aviv |Isreal      |50    |
|56783    |rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure|Boston   |USA         |79    |
|78783    |rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure|Boston   |USA         |79    |
|39526    |pallavi 56 >> 78 has no idea    |Hyderabad|India       |60    |
|78967    |rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know      |Hyderabad|India       |78    |
|08960    |rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know      |Hyderabad|India       |87    |
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
```

Since the `column name`s of two `dataFrames` matches the name of one `dataframe` needs to be `renamed` for `dropping` purpose later on

```
df1.withColumnRenamed("person Id", "Id").withColumnRenamed("person Name", "Name")
```

Now only steps left are join two dataframes, drop unnecessary columns and remove duplicates

```
df1.join(df2, df1("Id") === df2("person Id")).drop("Id", "Name").dropDuplicates("person Id", "person Name")
```

Final output is

```
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
|person Id|person Name                     |city Name|country Name|salary|
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
|78954    |rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur     |Mumbai   |India       |90    |
|78967    |rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know      |Hyderabad|India       |78    |
|56783    |ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent  |Seattle  |USA         |70    |
|56783    |rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure|Boston   |USA         |79    |
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
```

According to my understanding all the confusions of the question answered.

**Edited**

The above output is a `left join` so the final output seems not matching with the required output

A simple `right join` and change in `dropDuplicates` should have the required output

```
df1.join(df2, df1("Id") === df2("person Id"), "right").drop("Id", "Name").dropDuplicates("person Name")
```

Final output is

```
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
|person Id|person Name                     |city Name|country Name|salary|
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
|39526    |pallavi 56 >> 78 has no idea    |Hyderabad|India       |60    |
|34526    |paul 56 >> 78 has no idea       |Tel Aviv |Isreal      |60    |
|56783    |ram 12 > 4 matches intelligent  |Seattle  |USA         |70    |
|78954    |rahim 45 >> 6 doesn't occur     |Mumbai   |India       |90    |
|39526    |saul 96 >> 78 has no idea       |Delhi    |India       |60    |
|56783    |rahul 67 >> 6 will work for sure|Boston   |USA         |79    |
|78967    |rajesh 78 >> 4 I dont know      |Hyderabad|India       |78    |
|67526    |delta 89 >> 78 has no idea      |Tel Aviv |Isreal      |50    |
+---------+--------------------------------+---------+------------+------+
```